# Prove $x^n y^m \leq \frac{n^n m^m}{(n+m)^{n+m}}$ for $x + y = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

If $x > 0$, $y > 0$, x and y are real, and $x + y = 1$, prove that

$x^n y^m \leq \frac{n^n m^m}{(n+m)^{n+m}}$

for all positive integers n, m.

My proof attempts have been to apply two dimensional induction on n and m, but I haven't had much success. As this problem is in a section on differentiability and mean value theorems, I assume these apply to the problem somehow, but I'm not clear on exactly how.

Comment: Have you worked out upper bounds on $x$ and $y$ yet?

Comment: On simply x and y? Then they're given by x + y = 1, meaning 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < 1. So positive, integer powers of x and y tend to 0.

Comment: If $x,y \in Z^+$ and $x+y=1$ so there's only 2 cases

Comment: You are correct. I've indicated that x and y are real numbers, not integers. Thank you.

Comment: Considering that you are in a class on differentiability, were you taught Lagrange multipliers yet? Alternatively just substitute and differentiate.

Comment: The class I'm in is just an undergraduate real analysis course. Unfortunately, I've never heard of these multipliers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM we have

$$
\bigg(\big(\frac{x}{n}\big)^n\big(\frac{y}{m}\big)^m\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+m}}
\leq \frac{n\frac{x}{n}+m\frac{y}{m}}{n+m}=\frac{1}{n+m}.
$$

Comment: Ah hah! AM-GM has never been my strong suit. This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{aligned}x^ny^m=\frac{1}{m^nn^m}(mx)^n(ny)^m&\leqslant\frac{1}{m^nn^m}\left(\frac{n\times(mx)+m\times(ny)}{m+n}\right)^{m+n}\\&=\frac{1}{m^nn^m}\cdot\frac{(mn)^{m+n}}{(m+n)^{m+n}}\\&=\frac{m^mn^n}{(m+n)^{m+n}}\end{aligned}$$